# Apollo parse exception in Android

Tags: kotlin, graphql, kotlin-coroutines, graphql-js, graphql-java

Thanks in advance for help me.
In my previous code GraphQL code was working but we want to migrate the Aws Amplify when we added the Amplify after words i am getting the data in interceptor but after that getting exception-

"com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloParseException: Failed to parse http response"
"Parameter specified as non null is null method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter" not able to understand why it's happening.

Apollo version - 2.5.11
Kotlin version earlier - 1.5.30 now i am using 1.8.0
Gradle build earlier 7.0.2 now 7.4.2